# Is it possible to send a function from server to a client?

Tags: node.js

By my yet little understanding on how NodeJS/Javascript works, I believe it should be possible. Is it?

I would like to be able to send a function to a client based on http request, something like this (pseudo short code):

```
// Server
server.get("/function",()=>{
   return function () => {
     console.log('test)
}

// client
request ("server/function",(res)=>{
     func = res.body
     func()
// # result
// test
```

I have tried to convert to string to send the function from the server and convert back to an object on the client, but it return errors that I couldn't understand why as if I send a simple key value json object it works.

```
// server
const http = require('http');
const port = 3000;
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/function') {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        function func () {
            console.log('test')
        }
        res.end(func.toString())
    }
});

server.listen(3000)
```

```
// client
const http = require('http');

const httpGet = url => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.get(url, res => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let body = '';
            res.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
            res.on('end', () => resolve(body));
        }).on('error', reject);
    });
};

const call = async () => {
    const body = await httpGet('http://localhost:3000/function')
    console.log(`${body}`)
    func = JSON.parse(body) // try to redefine function based on the response
}

const func = () => {
    console.log('before')
}
func() // run the func defined here

call()

func() // run the function got from the request?
```

The idea is to have a client that will be able to execute almoust any code without the need of updating the client itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, **it is really unsafe** and you shouldn't have web applications that do this. But here goes:

Let's say you have a function:

```
function test() {
  console.log("test")
}
```

And as string:

```
const funcString = test.toString()
// ^ is now "function test() {\n  console.log(\"test\")\n }"
```

You need to first get the function body:

```
const funcBody = funcString.replace(/^[^{]+{/, '').replace(/}[^}]*$/, '')
// ^ is now "console.log(\"test\")"
```

Then create a function from it:

```
const newTest = Function(funcBody)
```

Now if you call `newTest()` you will see `test` printed in your console.

**Note that the regular expression I have used to get the function body will not work on all functions**. For example, for `const test = () => 1` you will need a different regular expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked as expected, including for both ways of declaring functions `function test() {}` and `const test = () => {}`. I do understand that is very dangerous. For now it is just for learning and understanding possibilities, but the idea will be using it in isolated environments and authentication and network ACLs, etc.

Comment: It will be running in a nodejs service, not web, something like a task runner on remote machines.

Comment: There is also `eval()` but I can't say this enough, please don't use it if you're not a 100% sure about what you are doing.

Comment: @Tuts yeah I realized as soon as I wrote it

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what I'm doing as I'm very beginner in NodeJS/Javascript, yet, I like making "experiments" on what I think that would be some interesting way of doing this, hehe... Thanks again for the advices.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure this is the best idea.**

Historically, the client-server relationship you are describing was inversed through [remote procedure calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) where the client would invoke a specific endpoint on a remote server. It sounds like your biggest draw towards having the client arbitrarily execute the code was the removal of updating the client code. What happens if you want to make backwards-incompatible changes to the server code? I think you will have better success using versioned API endpoints to execute code server-side based on client-side logic, which you will find many RPC and/or REST frameworks for within npm.

> The ideia is to have a client that will be able to execute almoust any code without the need of updating the client itself.

One final thing to keep in mind are the security implications of this. What happens if I find your client and substitute in my malicious JavaScript?

Comment: Hi. I understand the security concernments and totally agree with you. As I answered to @aravindan-ve, it is for learning and understanding possibilities, but the idea will be using it in isolated environments with authentication and network ACLs, etc.